# Ubuntu Docker-compose wordpress : configure on a specific port

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I manage to configure a wordpress site with docker-compose by using port 80 but it fails when I try to use another port.

The configuration works when I go to http://<my_server_ip> in my browser
It works for the configuration bellow:
I have the   ~/mysite/docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: secret
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - wp-net

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
            MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
    networks:
      - wp-net

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
      - ./wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content:ro
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - wordpress
    networks:
      - wp-net

networks:
  wp-net:

volumes:
  db_data:
```

I have the ~/mysite/nginx.conf

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://wordpress:80;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }
```

[image]

But it doesn't work when I try to set a specific port number
if I replace

- "80:80"

by

- "8070:80"

And I enter http://<my_server_ip>:8070  in my browser I don't have any answer

Do you know how to set up a specific port please?

Comment: The container still needs to use port 80 so don't change the nginx config

Comment: Also, the Wordpress image already includes a web server. You don't need nginx as well

Comment: The Nginx `listen` port needs to match the second `nginx: { ports: }` number.  I'd leave the container process listening on the standard HTTP port 80, even if you're remapping it to the outside host; so change it to `listen 80`.